# Use relatives bank account for my paycheck

Tags: taxes, banking, norway

I live in Sweden, and some family members live in Norway, recently I got a job in Norway, but I was unable to get a bank account here right away, and they can't put my pay on my Swedish account.

What will happen if they put my paycheck on one of my relatives account, and then that person transfers it to my account? Will something happen to their taxes or anything like that, will my relative or me be 'punished' in any way?

Comment: They could steal your money. Doubt they could be punished. Can the business not just print you a check for the first few months?

Comment: No that was not possible, they could delay it though, but I kinda needed it (to pay rent to my relatives...)